# Leaflet rendering one polygon in a list of polygons

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polygon

I have a leaflet map with django. I'm passing geojson from a database. For some reason, I'm not getting any errors, but it's only rendering one polygon instead of around 3,000. Everything else seems to be working correctly.

It's technically not a multipolygon since there aren't shapes inside this shape but a bunch of shapes rendered in the same place.

```
function initmap(){


            var map = new L.map('map',{

                            center: [1.0,1.0],
                            layers: [osmLayer,markers,parcelLayer],
            minZoom: 1,
                            zoom: 3 }
                    ).setView([lat,long],13 );


    }       



            var osmLayer = new  L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
                    subdomains: ['a','b','c']
    });



    var markers = new L.FeatureGroup();


    var parcelFeature = ['{"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h]]]}, "type": "Feature"}',
 '{"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[i,j],[k,l],[m,n],[o,p]]], "type": "Feature"}'];
     parcelFeature = JSON.parse(parcelFeature[0]);      

      var parcelLayer =  L.geoJson([parcelFeature],{
                     style : {

                   "color": "#000000",
                    "weight": 3,
                     "opacity": 10.65

                            }   
        });

            parcelLayer.on("loaded", function(e) {map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());} );      


    //marker icon
    var ceIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: "/static/maps/leaflet/images/somepng.png",
        iconSize: [45,45],
        iconAnchor:   [0, 0], 
        popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]  
    });



    //add markers

        marker = new L.marker([lat,long], {icon:ceIcon});
        markers.addLayer(marker);   

        marker = new L.marker([lat,long], {icon:ceIcon});
        markers.addLayer(marker);   

        marker = new L.marker([lat,long], {icon:ceIcon});
        markers.addLayer(marker);   

        marker = new L.marker([lat,long], {icon:ceIcon});
        markers.addLayer(marker);   



    initmap();
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a running sample where we can reproduce the same issue...jsfiddle or stackoverflow editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was pass this through django as a json and then splitting in javascript each json item and adding it to a new list.

```
var parcelFeature = [];
        var parcel_json = {{  parcel_json|safe }};


        for(i = 0; i < parcel_json.length; i++){
        var pjson = parcel_json[i];
        pjson = JSON.parse(pjson);
        parcelFeature.push(pjson);

        }
```

After this I used the default L.geoJson layer and it rendered correctly. Not sure the issue.

var parcelLayer =  L.geoJson(parcelFeature,
        { style :{

```
               "color": "#000000",
               "weight": 1,
               "opacity": 100},
       "fillColor":"#FFFFFF",   
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
               // does this feature have a property named popupContent?
                if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
               console.dir(feature.properties.popupContent);
             } }

   });
```